Error message: The 'DevTimeMonitorPackage' package did not load correctly
It's been few times that I receive this error while loading a project in Visual Studio 2022.
VS2022 is up to date. Problem seems to be related to "DevTimeMonitorPackage" package.
Anybody has an idea on the solution?
Partial dump (the end) of my ActivityLog.xml related to this error:
 <entry>
    <record>2631</record>
    <time>2024/09/16 14:38:14.297</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [DevTimeMonitorPackage]</description>
    <guid>{71CE9D33-78F7-4374-A75B-ABDAF8BF30CC}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2632</record>
    <time>2024/09/16 14:38:14.375</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [DevTimeMonitorPackage]Source: &apos;DevTimeMonitor&apos; Description: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=17.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. Le fichier sp&#x00E9;cifi&#x00E9; est introuvable.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=17.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. Le fichier sp&#x00E9;cifi&#x00E9; est introuvable.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=17.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at DevTimeMonitor.DevTimeMonitorPackage.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress`1 progress)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass21_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.&#x000D;&#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
    <guid>{71CE9D33-78F7-4374-A75B-ABDAF8BF30CC}</guid>
    <hr>0x80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
</activity>

Screenshot:

